# To what extent is the derived category of coherent sheaves on a scheme a "homotopy type" of the scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, soft-question

It is well known that the derived category of coherent sheaves (unbounded, bounded, and all cousins) on a scheme $X$ contain most - if not all (depending on specifics) - of the cohomological information about $X$.

I know there is no formal statement to this effect, but how inaccurate is to to think of the derived categories living over X as a kind of homotopy type of $X$?

Is there any hope of a "decomposition" of $X$ into a system $(X_{i})$ (say by iterated blowups) in such a way that the corresponding system of derived categories is an analogue of the Postnikov tower?

I apologise for how vague these questions are, I am just trying to centre myself in the theory.

Comment: Small comment: if $X$ is a variety over $\mathbf C$, we can also view it as topological space $X(\mathbf C)$. The quasicoherent derived categories (or even the isomorphism type of $X$ as an abstract scheme!) do not know everything about the classical homotopy type. For example, [Serre showed](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4011c/f1832.item) that for a smooth projective variety $X$ over $\mathbf C$ and an abstract field automorphism $\sigma$ of $\mathbf C$, the spaces $X(\mathbf C)$ and $^\sigma\!X(\mathbf C)$ can have different fundamental groups.

Comment: Maybe you're not asking about the comparison with the classical homotopy type, but if not then I'm not sure what you mean by 'a kind of homotopy type of $X$'.

Comment: True I have not been very specific. I guess what I mean by "homotopy type" ought to be a minimal collection of data encoding the information accessible by cohomological methods. Another essential piece is that this data be amenable to some sort of truncation or variation operation in the way the spaces have Postnikov decompositions.

Comment: I suppose I am picturing a world in which increasingly complex singularities are analogous to higher homtopical data. In this way the chain of blowups in a resolution of singularities (in characteristic 0) would be something like a Postnikov decomposition in reverse.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask about the singularity/homotopy analogy somewhere else, because after cursury thought it's not that ridiculous. After all, both higher homotopical features and singularities provid obstructions and complexity to algebraic avatars of the space. On the other hand this might be nonsense.

Comment: Informally, both derived categories and (stable) homotopy types provide a functor from a nonlinear category of spaces to a more linear category. Both formalisms relate to Grothendieck's idea of motives which is supposed to be a universal such functor. Indeed there are conjectural links between motives and derived categories, as well as adjoint functors between triangulated category of motives and A^1-stable homotopy category. Finally, one analogy for Postnikov towers in derived category is the concept of a semiorthognal decomposition.

Comment: Does this paper of Ayoub help at all? Just after (3.65) is a tower of blowups, the bottom of page 132 is about the limit of such a tower, and Lemma 2.4.5 is about the analogous Postnikov towers of sheaves. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.15004.pdf To me, as a model category theorist, I'd relate the two by saying both are right Bousfield localizations. To get at questions of convergence of the corresponding sequence of functors, I'd think about Goodwillie calculus. But I feel this is more homotopical than you wanted.

Comment: There are also several papers that try to recover $X$ from the (derived) category of coherent sheaves over $X$, e.g., this recent PhD thesis: https://hal.science/tel-04018741/document. On page 9 it also references the non-derived version of that question (Gabriel-Rosenberg reconstruction). Sequences of blow-ups, and the corresponding functors between model categories are also treated by Orlov: Smooth and proper noncommutative schemes and gluing of DG categories